# jQuery does not load on localhost page

Tags: jquery, html

I have added following line to update jQuery in header file

```
<script src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js'></script>
<script> $(document).ready(function() { alert('Yup I am working'); }); </script>
```

It gives alert 'Yup I am working'.
But when I check jQuery version on console using jQuery().jquery it shows 2.1.3.
Can you please tell me why jQuery is not updating?

Comment: You don't need to update JS files; they are retrieved from the server and stored in the browser cache, which you can usually force refresh by pressing CTRL+F5. Might you have another version of jQuery loaded by your HTML file?

Comment: Try clearing the cache of your browser and trying again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that you don't include jQuery 2.1.3 later on the page until the closing `</body>` tag!

Open your page as source code only and `CTRL+F` or `CMD+F` for all `.js` go trough it, you will find another included jQuery somewhere. Remove it, you only want to include jQuery once!

Answer (score 1):

When you add remote file in your localhost or production server, at that time I suggest you to use CDN library.

Please go through below and find appropriate JS.

https://cdnjs.com/libraries/jquery/